# RDS Migration - MySQL Queries have slowed down

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

We recently moved to Amazon Web Services from colo hosting. We have two EC2 servers and a RDS instance. Initally everything was running quite smoothly but recently queries that used to take seconds to run are now taking minutes.

We tried upgrading to a larger instance but that does not seemed to have helped. Also, Ive reached the limit of my knowledge and we are stil in the process of trying to find a new DBA after the last one left.

Our RDS is a m3.xlarge and we are using SSD storage. Below is a screenshot of max Read and Write ops as well as CPU usage

Any suggestions or guidance on paramaters that I should check or should change would be much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are many reasons to slow down a database. With the cloudwatch diagrams, do you have any other database performance  tool in your network? Second, if there is no change recently (include code and database changes), and you have enabled `multi-AZ` in that RDS, can you try to stop it, the RDS will be auto-failover to another available zone, any improvement?

Comment: Off-topic (perhaps try http://serverfault.com/ or http://dba.stackexchange.com/). Downvoted because the bounty prevents proper migration. It would be better if the two graphs showed the same time frame.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are having a latency problem, i. e. low availability.

Amazon EBS drives, like almost everything on the cloud, are shared.

And, like everything on the cloud, you can pay extra for maximum peak or extra for minimum availability (or extra for both, of course).

(sorry for being obvious)

Now the tips:

See those low valleys in between the huge peaks on your IOPS graph? That probably doesn't mean your RDBMS isn't requesting them, but that it is not getting them instead, because Amazon is giving those IOPS to other, less IOPS greedy users. But many of them.

If you haven't done so already, read about [Provisioned IOPS](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/details/#PIOPS) for low latency SSD disk access,

and [how to improve EBS performance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSPerformance.html).

Also, is [EBS optimization](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#ebs) active for your instance? Amazon docs say it is enabled by default for c4 instances and supported by m3.xlarge instances, but doesn't mention anything about the optimization being enabled by default for the latter.

I am not in any case an expert, but there is no harm and almost no cost on trying those simple solutions. That should probably be enough. Otherwise, don't wait till you manage to hire a new competent DBA and get some consulting from a reputable firm ASAP (Or even buying [AWS premium support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/signup/) for a month). At least they will be able to tell where the bottleneck is and what has to be done to fix it.